# UIDatePicker Crash in iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, ios9, uidatepicker

I used `UIDatePicker` in my `ViewController`.
it worked fine on `iOS 8.x`,
but when I run it on `iOS 9.x` devices，it crashed.

I have tried to create a new project to use `UIDatePicker` in the same way and it worked fine on all iOS devices.

So, my question is whether my project setting was wrong or the way I uesd `UIDatePicker` was wrong.

The crash information is:

[click to see the crash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFpWn.jpg)

I hava set a breakpoint, it just crash at **_datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;** on iOS 9.3, and worked fine on iOS 8.1.

```
- (UIDatePicker *)datePicker {
    if (!_datePicker) {
        NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];
        _datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
        _datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        _datePicker.hidden = YES;
        _datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [_datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
    return _datePicker;
}
```

Comment: Set a exception brakepoint to catch the crash

Comment: Can you please put your code?

Comment: I think There is something mistakes in Hierarchy of view and picker view.

Comment: you are set height in picker view?

Comment: Try : [myDatePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot it doesn`t worked.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of iOS 9 Update as reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709525/ios9-uidatepicker-with-datepickermode-of-uidatepickermodetime-only-shows-hours) that is already answered.
update your code like below.

```
  _datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
  _datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
  _datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

> UIPickerView and UIDatePicker are now resizable and
>   adaptive—previously, these views would enforce a default size even if
>   you attempted to resize them. These views also now default to a width
>   of 320 points on all devices, instead of to the device width on
>   iPhone. Interfaces that rely on the old enforcement of the default
>   size will likely look wrong when compiled for iOS 9. Any problems
>   encountered can be resolved by fully constraining or sizing picker
>   views to the desired size instead of relying on implicit behavior.